# GridView behaves weird; duplicates TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-gridview

So i got a GridView displaying some flags. Each GridView cell consists of an ImageView and a TextView. Only the ImageView is shown at start. When position 1 and 240 in the GridView loads, the TextView should become visible.

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mVHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.grid_images, parent, false);
        mVHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mVHolder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_img);
        mVHolder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textas);
        mVHolder.mTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        convertView.setTag(mVHolder);
    } else {
        mVHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    int img = Flagcontainer.flags.get(position).getFlagThumb();


    Picasso.with(mContext).load(img).into(mVHolder.mImageView);

    if (position == 1 || position == 240) {
        mVHolder.mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mTextView;
}
```

**The problem:**

When scrolled all the way to the bottom of the GridView, the TextView of cell 240 gets displayed. If one scrolls up, TextViews of other cells than 1 and 240 gets displayed.

What is wrong with my code?

See the video to visualize the problem

**Video:**
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONLLvS9ISJQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as el_bhm pointed out this bit

```
if (position == 1 || position == 240) {
    mVHolder.mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

needs an else where `mVHolder.mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: It's the visibility. It needs to be set at each getView, after creating or getting a ViewHolder. Finding again views within a ViewHolder partioaly defeats the purpose of this pattern, isn't it?

Comment: @el_bhm yes i miss understood the problem

Comment: Thanks guys! I don't know how i missed that.